# TikZ: vertical rule between columns with differently sized cells

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw a rule separating two columns. Unfortunately, it won't work properly if the cells have different widths. Are there any known workarounds?

My code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]{
a & b & c \\
d & long row & e \\
f & g & h \\
};
\draw (m-1-2.north east -| m-3-2.south east) -| (m-3-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result (notice the rule intersecting the long cell):
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]{
\node(a){a}; & \node(b){b}; & \node(s1){}; & \node(c){c}; \\
\node(d){d}; & \node(long){long row}; & \node(s2){}; & \node(e){also long}; \\
\node(f){f}; & \node(g){g}; & \node(s3){}; & \node(h){h}; \\
};
\draw[red] (s1.north) -- (s3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that this won't work if the cell containing `e` is longer than the cells `c` and `h`. Add some more characters to cell `e` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Also, the rule won't be straight anymore if cell `c` is wider than cell `h`, or vice versa.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a blank spacer column, through which you could draw the line. Not the most elegant solution, but it may work.

Comment: That isn't too elegant, that's true - but it works. Thanks a lot! I wonder whether there's a way to force all cells in a column to be of equal width, as it would make things much easier. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: You could use `row sep=` and `col sep=`, but then the spacer cell approach wouldn't work. Can you use one of the tabular environments instead? That might be better than the TikZ matrix for what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How would `row/column sep` exactly help? Unfortunately I can't use a tabular environment because the actual tikz picture is much more complex than the example that I posted.

Comment: It would only allow you to set the spacing, but it it wouldn't fix your line problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the `text width` for those `node`s to be the width of the `long row` and `align=center`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes]{
a & |[text width=\widthof{long row},align=center]|b & c \\
d & |[align=center]|long row & e \\
f & |[text width=\widthof{long row},align=center]|g & h \\
};
\draw (m-1-2.north east -| m-3-2.south east) -| (m-3-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update:

You can fix the `text width` for the entire second column by adding

```
column 2/.style={nodes={text width=\widthof{long row},align=center}}
```

to the `matrix` options.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, 
                   column 2/.style={nodes={text width=\widthof{long row},align=center}}]{
a & b & c \\
d & long row & e \\
f & g & h \\
};
\draw (m-1-2.north east -| m-3-2.south east) -| (m-3-2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's interesting. However, it's pretty inconvenient having to specify `long row` for each cell. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @watain Please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

Add empty cells with optinal text height to adjust placement of rule.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
a & b &|[text height=1em]| & c \\
d & long row && e \\
f & g &|[text height=1em]|& h \\
};
\draw[red] (m-1-2.north east -| m-3-3.south) -| (m-3-3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]